# Spring batch job is not terminating after adding Splunk logging step

Tags: spring-batch, log4j2, splunk

I am running a Spring batch but for logging purposes, I am redirecting all my logs to Splunk. The logs are getting updated on Splunk as expected, but now my job is not terminating. Even after everything gets processed, it's still running.

How can I terminate my job with Splunk logging enabled?

**log4j2.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="cspprovmi"
               packages="com.prov">

    <Appenders>
        <SplunkHttp name="http" url="${env:SPLUNK_URL}"
                    token="${env:SPLUNK_TOKEN}"  host="${env:SPLUNK_NAMESPACE}"
                    index="cba_facts_cs" source="${env:SPLUNK_SOURCE}"
                    sourcetype="facts_cs:http:log" messageFormat="json"
                    disableCertificateValidation="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg" />
        </SplunkHttp>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="http" level="info" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**pom.xml :**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

**JobBuilderConfig.java**

```
  //  Job
    @Bean
    public Job job(){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobCSProvMI4275")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .next(step3())
                .next(step4())
                .next(step5())
                .next(step6())
                .next(step7())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
    }
}
```

One workaround I am considering is to include `jobListener` and call `system.exit(0)` in the code itself. This seems to work fine, as it's terminating job even with Splunk logging enabled, but not sure if there is a better way to achieve this (ie exit the process gracefully).

```
   @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener jobMi4275ExecutionListener() {
        JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener = new JobExecutionListener() {
            @Override
            public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                LOGGER.info("jobCSP4275 Started executing..");
            }
            @Override
            public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                LOGGER.info("jobCSP4275 finished successfully..Exiting job !!");
              
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        return jobExecutionListener;
    }
```

Comment: How are you running your job (in a single JVM, in a webapp, etc)? Based on what you shared, your job should finish after completing step7. If it does not stop, this could mean that step7 is still running (if it's a chunk-oriented step, are you sure its item reader returns null at some point?) or there is a resource that is running in the background and preventing the JVM from exiting (like a thread pool for example). Please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: Yes, the background process is the log4j which I have added to reroute the logging from my local to Splunk. The config is in log4j2.xml. It was terminating fine in my local but as soon as I add the log4j config. The process is not terminating and I have to forcefully send the exit signal. But now, as it's not completing gracefully, the status is getting captured as UNKNOWN instead of COMPLETED in the batch table.

Comment: So, I would like to know how to integrate log4j shutdown signal with spring batch so that I can remove the system.exit code and gracefully shutdown the job once it's completed.

Comment: What do you mean by "log4j shutdown signal"? I'm not sure logging is what preventing your JVM from stopping. Again, please share a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: @praveenks, did you managed to solve this problem??  I'm also having the similar trouble now.. It will be very helpful if some one already solved this..